# How do I set a Guid using Microsoft Unity

Tags: unity-container

I don't get it. I can't find any docs on this seemingly innocuous problem. I have tried 4 different formats:

1) brace+lower

```
<property name="DefaultImpactID" propertyType="System.Guid">
                <value value="{fbfa75c0-a0a0-40e2-a239-c5c6b7435fa6}"/>
              </property>
```

2) brace+upper

```
<property name="DefaultImpactID" propertyType="System.Guid">
                <value value="{67A05AC6-AB4D-47DD-AFC7-EE44FC2D6FAF}"/>
              </property>
```

3) nobrace+upper

```
<property name="DefaultImpactID" propertyType="System.Guid">
                <value value="67A05AC6-AB4D-47DD-AFC7-EE44FC2D6FAF"/>
              </property>
```

4)nobrace+lower

```
<property name="DefaultImpactID" propertyType="System.Guid">
                <value value="fbfa75c0-a0a0-40e2-a239-c5c6b7435fa6"/>
              </property>
```

always get the same error: System.InvalidOperationException: The value for the property "DefaultImpactID" could not be resolved. --->  System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid..

Answer (score 1):

nevermind. you just have to spec the type on the value element, like this:

```
 <property name="DefaultUrgencyID" propertyType="System.Guid">
                <value type="System.Guid" value="67a05ac6-ab4d-47dd-afc7-ee44fc2d6faf"/>
              </property>
```

(you don't have to for strings!)